# Find count of consecutive similar values in a column - Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table which gets stale(similar) values after a certain period of time. I want to find the count of the last consecutive values. Can you please help me write a Oracle SQL query for this? I have printed the sample input and output below.

Input:

```
ID   date         value
2641 02/01/2019    5.6
2641 02/04/2019    5.7
2641 02/05/2019    6.2
2641 02/06/2019    6.2
2641 02/07/2019    4.3 
2641 02/08/2019    4.3
2641 02/11/2019    4.3
2641 02/12/2019    4.3
2641 02/13/2019    4.3
2641 02/14/2019    4.3
2641 02/15/2019    4.3
2641 02/18/2019    4.3
2641 02/19/2019    4.3
2642 02/01/2019    7.6
2642 02/04/2019    4.7
2642 02/05/2019    5.2
2642 02/06/2019    3.8
2642 02/07/2019    3.8
2642 02/08/2019    3.8
2642 02/11/2019    3.8
2642 02/12/2019    3.8
2642 02/13/2019    3.8
2642 02/14/2019    3.8
2642 02/15/2019    3.8
2642 02/18/2019    3.8
2642 02/19/2019    3.8
```

Output

```
ID   stale_days
2641  9  
2642  10
```

Regards,
Sawan

Comment: I edited your post to format the input and output tables. You just edited your post to undo what I did. **WHY**???

Comment: Sorry. I did not see your edit. I tried to format it after posting. I have now reverted it back to the way you had edited it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like that.

The idea is for each row to get the max value of all the rows coming after and the min value of all the rows coming after. If the value is the same as the min and max, you count them.

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT 
    ID, 
    VALUE,
    MIN(VALUE) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY D ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS MIN_NEXT,
    MAX(VALUE) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY D ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS MAX_NEXT
  FROM T
) WHERE VALUE=MIN_NEXT AND VALUE=MAX_NEXT
GROUP BY ID;
```

For the test : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/046b1/1

Answer (score 0):

```
    with rows_with_cons_val as
    (
    select t.*, rowid, row_number() over (partition by id, value order by date_entered) 
    rid 
    from t) 
    select id, rid as stale_days
    from (
    select r.*, max(date_entered) over (partition by id) as selection
    from rows_with_cons_val r) where date_entered = selection;
```

Comment: Hummmm ... not sure it works :( look at what happens if on the before last row you put 3.7 :  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4feebc/1

Comment: The assumption here is that you wouldn't have two different values in the same day. If so, then this has to be a timestamp and not date, i guess.

Comment: Ohh there is indeed a problem on my sqlfiddle. But even without the duplicated date, here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e81d06/1. In this example, based on the problem, result for the second id should be 1 not 9. I think ;)